# Probability of being still in the system in a queue system

Tags: stochastic-processes, exponential-distribution, queueing

I have one queue with two servers $S_1$ and $S_2$.The serving times are modeled $\sim exp(\mu_1)$ and  $\sim exp(\mu_2)$ respectively.

The first server is free while the second has two clients, $A$ whose service is in progress and $B$ that is waiting. There is a path for every client so each of them must be served first by $S_1$ and then by $S_2$.
Then another client $X$ arrives.
Now, help me developing this concept:

1. $P_b$, the probability that customer B is still in the system when $S_1$ finishes to serve $X$.

Talking in terms of times, let $T_1$ the time used to serve $X$ and let $T_2$ the time used to serve $B$ after $S_2$ finished to serve A.
Then, that means that I want $T_A+T_B>T_1$.

But I don't know how to transpose this into probability.

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Probability of service in a queue theory problem with exponential random variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/497888/probability-of-service-in-a-queue-theory-problem-with-exponential-random-variabl)

Comment: No, here I'm asking another probability. I want to know the probability that the customer B is still in the system when $S_1$ finishes to serve $X$.

In that question we wondered the $P(T_1 < T_2)$, here we are asking for $P(T_A+ T_B > T_1 )$